# Use NGINX as a proxy to terminate SSL and forward request to target with HTTP

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

**Assumptions**

- Client requests target websites using *HTTPS*
- NGINX server is passed as *HTTP* proxy for said requests
- Client and NGINX server can share an SSL certificate

**Objective**

Allow NGINX to decrypt the request and forward it via HTTP to the end target.

**Conclusion**

Given that this is possible, what is the technique called and how is it implemented in NGINX?

Comment: It is called ReverseProxy - there is quite alot of info about it out there

Comment: That's really not enough. what I'm trying to achieve is MITM / Traffic Interception

Comment: A MitM is little more than an illegitimate reverse proxy, so @Orphans' comment is on point and exactly what you're describing.

Comment: Or you're looking for a TLS capable proxy in which case NGINX isn't the right tool and product recommendations are off-topic.